# Django REST DateTimeField adds 0000+00:00 to datetime object

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-datetime

I'm working on a project where I have a serializer with 2 DateTimeFields:

`createdAt = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True,format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')`

`updatedAt = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True,allow_null=True,format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')`

The input data for those 2 fields are:

`"createdAt":  datetime.strptime("2021-06-22T11:17:09.460Z", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'),`

`"updatedAt":  datetime.strptime("2021-06-24T06:50:58.030Z", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'),`

However, things don't go smoothly because when I check the validated_data, those fields have this structure:

`createdAt: 2021-06-22 11:17:09.460000+00:00`

`updatedAt: 2021-06-24 06:50:58.030000+00:00`

Is there any reason why those 4 zeros and the +00:00 are added? I have checked the documentation about this, even the ISO-8601 in Wikipedia, but I haven't been able to find a clue about why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the datetime formats you've set in serializer fields are used to represent the dates in string format (in other words, it's how Django converts a timestamp into a string representation, to be returned by API.

When you mention `validated_data` it means you're looking at the opposite direction of the conversion — string representations of timestamps are converted into actual timestamps.

`2021-06-22 11:17:09.460000+00:00` looks like an actual timestamp, printed in Python. There are 6 numbers for microseconds and a timezone offset.

I'd check the type of this value, probably it's not even a string, but a datetime instance.

Comment: Hi Igor Pomaranskiy, yes it is a datetime in validated_data. What I don't understand is why the input fields are like that even though I transformed them using datetime.strptime

Comment: @JavierRomero. because you use `DateTimeField`, which, in turn, converts values into datatime instances. Which, by the way, is totally OK and it's not clear for me why do you bother about it at all.

Comment: For some reason the client wants it that way and specifies that it should be 2021-06-28T09:00:00.000Z and still be datetime format, that's why

Comment: @JavierRomero. that's totally OK. When your serializer will _return_ data, it will be exactly in the format you've set in the field settings. But on DB side it should be stored as an ordinary datetime. So I don't see a reason to bother about coversion.

Comment: I talked to the project manager and they found that there was a mistake in the documentation on how we were supposed to work with it internally. Thanks so much for the explanation, I'm a complete noob in Django REST and I had no idea about this.

Comment: @JavierRomero. you're welcome. In case, the issue is resolved, you can mark my response as correct.